# Transition on Mount and Unmount

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions, transition

basically I want to do smth like:

```
visible ?
<Fade>
   <SomeComponent/>
</Fade> 
: undefined
```

So I want to transit single elemnts for now, and wouldn't really like to manage the Fade's state from a parent component.

I just want the Fade to be triggered on mount and on unmount.
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends but you can do it in css with keyframes

ex:

```
@keyframes myAnimation {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
  100%   { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
 animation:         myAnimation 5s;
```

Comment: Yeah, but that just a static animation. If I unmount it before I fade it out then I wont see any fade. Basically I when I unmount a component, before unmount I want to trigger an animation, wait it, then unmount.

Comment: Should I just make a HOC? or would that be a bad practice in this case?

Comment: It will depend on the context of it. for this it case probably you will have a big effort for a "small" thing